# C# - DataTable Out of Memory exception in application to catch SQL Server "INSERT" events

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, out-of-memory

I have been tasked with creating an application that monitors any "INSERT" events on a specific table. I was going to go about this using SqlDependency to create a notification link between the DB and the C# app, but it turns out I am not able to do this due to security issues.

Due to this, I have modeled my application as follows:

[image]

This is well and good, but as it turns out, the SQL table I am querying has a rather large size. The table has nearly 3.5 Million rows 55 columns. When loading into the C# DataTable object, I am getting an out of memory exception.

```
internal static DataTable ExecuteQuery(string query, Dictionary<string,string> parameters = null)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection dbconn = new SqlConnection(SQLServer.Settings.ConnectionString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                dbconn.Open(); // Open the connection
                cmd.CommandText = query; // Set the query text
                cmd.Connection = dbconn;
                if (parameters != null)
                {
                    foreach (var parameter in parameters) // Add filter parameters
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
                }
                var dt = new DataTable();
                using (SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)){adpt.Fill(dt);} // MY ERROR OCCURS HERE!
                dbconn.Close();
                queryError = false;
                return dt;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            queryError = true;
            EventLogger.WriteToLog("ExecuteQuery()", "Application", "Error: An error has occured while performing a database query.\r\nException: " + ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

When running the code above, I get the following error at the line for `SqlDataAdapter.Fill(dt)`

> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Is there a way that I can either restructure my application OR prevent this incredibly high memory consumption from the DataTable class? SQL server seems capable enough to do a select * from the table but when I fill a DataTable with the same data, I use up over 6GB of RAM! Why is there so much overhead when using DataTable?

Here is a link to my [flowchart](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7_6TSq9NxvNdGZraU5ULURvQXc/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn't want to use a trigger within SQL Server to do this?

Comment: What is the average size of each row? Multiply this by the number of rows. How much "overhead" does the DT incur (at maximum)? *Anyway,* SQL server *streams* the result set in this example, so it does not need to be materialized all at once. On the other hand, DataTables only exist in memory and are 'loaded all at once'.

Comment: you also can consider SQL built-in mechanism like Auditing and Versioning, if they are avail on your SQL version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by making use of the [`SqlDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx)class. This class lets you "stream" the sql result set row by row rather bringing back the entire result set all at once and loading that into memory.

So now in step 5 from the flow chart, I can query for only the very first row. Then in step 6, I can query again at a later date and iterate through the new result set one row at a time until I find the original row I started at. All the while, I am filling a DataTable with the new results. This accomplishes two things.

1. I don't need to load all the data from the query all at once into local memory.
2. I can immediately get the "inverse" DataSet. AKA... I can get the newly inserted rows that didn't exist the first time I checked.

Which is exactly what I was after. Here is just a portion of the code:

```
private static SqlDataReader reader;
private static SqlConnection dbconn = new SqlConnection(SQLServer.Settings.ConnectionString);

private void GetNextRows(int numRows)
    {
        if (dbconn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            OpenConnection();

        // Iterate columns one by one for the specified limit.
        int rowCnt = 0;
        while (rowCnt < numRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                    object[] row = new object[reader.FieldCount];
                    reader.GetValues(row);
                    resultsTable.LoadDataRow(row, LoadOption.PreserveChanges);
                    rowCnt++;
                    sessionRowPosition++;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The whole class would be too large for me to post here but one of the caveats was that the interval between checks for me was long, on the order of days, so I needed to close the connection between checks. When closing the connection with a SqlDataReader, you loose your row position so I needed to add a counter to keep track of that.

Answer (score 0):

Check you query for select. You probably get from database many rows.